# MFP 7 and Apple Watch

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

Our application is built using hybrid technology provided by Worklight 6.2 and we are planning to upgrade to MFP 7.

Does MFP7 provide an Apple watch environment to support our hybrid app that can be added?

I was looking to the following URL:

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_setting_up_new_wl_environment.html

and couldn't find any document about apple watch except if I need to go native which is not suitable for our scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Worklight/MobileFirst Platform Foundation does not provide a watch-specific environment. You can however do some watch development. Review the following blog posts, detailing implementation instructions for the Apple Watch environment:

- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/07/22/serving-data-to-the-apple-watch-other-wearables-with-ibm-mobilefirst/
- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/06/18/mobilefirst-tweet-notifications/
- You can find more by more googling

Note that authentication support is limited.

Comment: Thank you Idan for the help